# Get the same UUID on different Linux distributions

Tags: uuid, dmidecode

```
# dmidecode --string system-uuid
```

I'm using the code above get the UUID on each host in my environment. As far as I understand the UUID should not change between different Linux distributions on the same host with the same hardware configuration. But after some tests on different Linux distributions I encountered different uuid with this same command.

It seems that older `dmidecode` version will get different UUID result.

For example `dmidecode 2.9` from SLES11.2 result with `string A` and `dmidecode 2.12` from Debian 8 result with `string B`.

How can I get the same uuid no matter the Linux distribution I deploy on my machine?

**Additional information:**

I wanted to use `dmidecode` and not MAC address as UUID because i saw that if I replace my network adapter or some other hardware's settings the UUID will not change.

What I need is some unique identifier that I can have on my machine to identify it across minor hardware changes and different OS. Using `dmidecode` cannot be fake in some level I guess instead of just generating UUID and writing it to a file and using it.

I'm working with VMware and machine clones are often used and that's why I need something that will not be replicated with the clone.

Comment: what do you need to know is the same?  the distro and version?

Comment: Not sure about system-uuid, but would the NIC's MAC-address work?

Comment: The uuid represents the host in my data base and that how I know what record to update. Do you recommend using mac address as my uuid?

Comment: What are the two values from dmidecdode? And if these were installed from a package what is that package information for that?

Comment: the value are uuid strings but they are different from one to another depending on the dmidecode version. it does not matter from what package dmidecode come from but the bin version. for example dmidecode 2.9 from sles11.2 result with string A and dmidecode 2.12 from debian 8 result with string B.(i don't want to publish the strings because of security matters). my main question is how to get one repeated uuid between all os's on the same host.

Comment: I wonder what the differences are for dmidecode output without the '--string system-uuid' parameters across the versions. Possibly instead of depending on the parameter you could pass the result to 'sha1sum' or something - after culling the differences if any.

Answer (score 2):

It's sw, it changes whether you want it or not :)

I wouldn't rely on it (and pretty much on any sw or hw-based auto-detected info) for a DB index - both hw and sw may have to be changed and if the info changes as a result you have to start over. Could be even worse - if you can get duplicates your DB will be in trouble.

I'd use an asset management tool for the index - to guarantee its uniqueness - and I'd map the auto-detected info (MAC, HDD, RAM, CPU, uuid, whatever) to the index but as separate/independent values, not blobbed up into a single value. This way you would locate the machine by single/multi-value queries (in most cases), falling back to the index/asset management system as needed. You can also handle hw/sw upgrades/swaps which add/change/remove one or more of the info values (updated uuid, for example).

Comment: Or use one of the numerous FOSS tool to do it for me...

Comment: I do not understand, how is this number created and what is diferent with FOSS tools to maintain uniqueness?

Answer (score 0):

I use `hostname`:

```
 i = gethostname(tmp,2047); 
 if (i)                     /* found host name */
     strcpy(wrk,tmp);
```

which if not changing a lot :-) is good.

Comment: I think that the question requires id "to identify it across minor hardware changes and different OS". A hostname can be hardly used for reliable identification across OS.